# Option implied data from CME

Tags: options, quantlib, american-options

I am trying to extract the `risk free rate and volatility` from the traded American options with expiry Nov-2020 from CME. https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/precious/gold_quotes_globex_options.html#optionProductId=192&strikeRange=ATM

I took prior settlement price and date as the calculation date. A snapshot of data that I used is as follows -

[image]

I used `Python-quantlib` library to do all calculations -

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd
import scipy

calculationday = ql.Date(18, 8, 2020)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculationday
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()

future = 2013.1
optiondata = pd.concat([
                        pd.DataFrame({'optiontype' : ['P']*10,
                                        'strike' : [1950.0, 1955.0, 1960.0, 1965.0, 1970.0, 1975.0, 1980.0, 1985.0, 1990.0, 1995.0],
                                        'expiry' : [ql.Date(27, 10, 2020)]*10,
                                        'price' : [45.70, 47.70, 49.70, 51.90, 54.10, 56.40, 58.70, 61.10, 63.60, 66.10]
                                    }),
                        pd.DataFrame({'optiontype' : ['C']*10,
                                        'strike' : [1950.0, 1955.0, 1960.0, 1965.0, 1970.0, 1975.0, 1980.0, 1985.0, 1990.0, 1995.0],
                                        'expiry' : [ql.Date(27, 10, 2020)]*10,
                                        'price' : [108.80, 105.80, 102.80, 100.00, 97.20, 94.50, 91.80, 89.20, 86.70, 84.20]
                                    })
                    ], ignore_index = True, sort = False)

def loss(parameters, data = optiondata):
    riskfree = parameters[0]/100  
    div = parameters[0]/100  
    vol = parameters[1]/100  
    optionprice = np.zeros(data.shape[0])
    for i in np.arange(data.shape[0]):
        optionparam = ql.VanillaOption(ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(1 if data['optiontype'][i] == 'C' else -1, data['strike'][i]), 
                                                    ql.AmericanExercise(calculationday, data['expiry'][i]))
        priceprocess = ql.BlackScholesMertonProcess(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(future)), 
                                                       ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(calculationday, div, ql.Actual360())), 
                                                       ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(calculationday, riskfree, ql.Actual360())), 
                                                       ql.BlackVolTermStructureHandle(ql.BlackConstantVol(calculationday, calendar, vol, ql.Actual360())))
        binomial_engine = ql.BinomialVanillaEngine(priceprocess, "crr", 1300)
        optionparam.setPricingEngine(binomial_engine)
        optionprice[i] = optionparam.NPV()
    return np.sum(np.square(data['price'] - optionprice))

minimize(loss, [0, 10], method = 'trust-constr', constraints = NonlinearConstraint(lambda x: np.array( [ x[0], x[1] ] ), 0., np.inf))
```

With above implementation, I got `risk free rate` as 1.03418556% (continuously compounding) and `volatility` as 21.10113888%

However I have doubt if above calculation is really right because the implied risk-free rate is still looking quite large.

Could you please point if above calculation makes sense?

Comment: I don't know python quantlib so I don't really know what the code mean. But since this is an option on future and the price process of a future is different from that of a stock, you may want to check if this is a code that have taken this into account.

Comment: The only difference I am confident about is that under risk neutral measure Future price is martingale, which is incorporated by considering div yield equals to risk free rate

Comment: If so I think the "risk free rate" you obtained would be risk free rate + cost of carry (say inventory cost for gold in your example).

Comment: is there any way to extract the cost of carry from the available information?

Comment: Stictly speaking, it's not correct to price it by simply setting dividend equal to risk free rate. What I said above about risk free rate + cost of carry is not really correct but just "somewhat" correct. I've never worked on this rigorously, better wait for someone else to answer.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why is it wrong to set div equal to risk free rate for Future as underlying? This is what we learned from various financial engg book, is not the case?

Comment: That's because of the presence of the inventory cost. If there is no other cost of carry, I think it is correct.